# How to run angular cli ng test with production build settings and AOT enabled

Tags: angular-cli, angular2-aot

Is there a way to run the angular cli tests with the command `ng test` that tells the underlining compiler to use the `ng build --prod` settings?

I ask because here are often aot compilation errors encountered with `ng build --prod` that **do not occur with normal compilation** with `ng build`

Comment: Any clue on that? I think that's a very important point.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, and I think that is because the test architect target is its own build configuration. Options like assets, scripts, and styles are supported, but options that are typically associated with production, like AOT, are not. This is because the compiler team [considers the feature to be experimental](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/8007). There is a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6650) to support AOT.

To create a production configuration, add it to the test target.

```
"test": {
  "builder: "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
  "options": {
    ...
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does anyone has any up-to-date info on this experimental feature? Maybe @Trevor Karjanis? Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried `ng build --aot` ?

https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

To test with production settings you could use `ng test --environment=prod`.

Comment: Thing is that adding --environment=prod will not trigger what --prod flag triggers, especially minification (which is my main source of troubles). I truly wander how real prod builds can actually be tested.